# Java programming help and android development

Tags: java, android, image, if-statement, touch-event

I am trying to draw an image over another image when a user touches the screen.  But the image only appears when the user touches and then disappears when they let go of the screen.

This is my if method:

```
int RED = 0;
int GREEN = 1;
Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
int len = touchEvents.size();

if (RED == 0) {
    ready = Assets.readybtntwo;
}

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

    if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP){
        updateWaiting(touchEvents);
        RED +=1;

        if (RED == 0)
            ready = Assets.readybtntwo;

        if(RED == 1)
            ready = Assets.readybtngreentwo;
    }

    g.drawPixmap(ready, 0, 0);
}
```

Sorry I'm using a framework built from the book beginning android games.  But it shouldn't matter, I want the image to stay forever and terminate the if loop.

Comment: It sounds like you want the image to appear when they touch, and stay on the screen even after they let go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error here. It looks like the variable `RED` is local to your method if the above code is all inside the touch event handler. This means that when the user touches the screen each time it's reset to 0 and then becomes 1 again. This probably isn't what you want.

The reason that it's only rendered is that g.drawPixmap will either be submitting an element to a draw queue or rendering it immediately. This method to draw the button is only ever being drawn when you have a touch event!

Instead, you could have a boolean drawGreenReadyButton value as a class member, i.e.

```
private boolean drawGreenReadyButton = false;
```

Then you can change that inner if statement to the following:

```
if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP){
    updateWaiting(touchEvents);
    drawGreenReadyButton = true;
}
```

And inside your main rendering loop rather than in the touch event handler put:

```
if(drawGreenReadyButton) {
    g.drawPixmap(Assets.readybtngreentwo, 0, 0);
} else {
    g.drawPixmap(Assets.readybtntwo, 0, 0);
}
```

Also, consider using `TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN` rather than `TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP`, so that the button is shown green as soon as they touch the screen, not when they lift their finger up.

Comment: I tried that and it draws neither until i click and when i click it draws one and immediatly takes it down any other suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't see the `inside your main rendering loop rather than in the touch event handler put` part. The reasoning here is that in your main rendering loop where you draw everything you always need to be submitting a button to draw, whether it's green or the other one. If you tell it to draw the button in your touch event handler then it will only draw the button when you touch and will remove it when the canvas is refreshed next frame.